# Why does the REBOL layout seem to be persistent?

Tags: static, foreach, rebol

I have this code:

```
REBOL [Title: "Employee list"]

screen1: does [

    emp-list: [
        "Amy" 1
        "Bob" 2
        "Carrie" 3
    ]

    gui-layout: [ text "click your name" ]

    foreach [emp-name emp-id] emp-list [
        append gui-layout compose/deep [
        box (emp-name) [screen2 (emp-id)]
        ]
    ]

    view layout gui-layout
]

screen2: func [emp-id] [

    choice-list: [
        "A" 11
        "B" 22
    ]

    gui-layout: [
        box "<-- back to names" [screen1]
        text reform ["clicked id " emp-id ", now choose below"]
    ]

    foreach [choice-name choice-id] choice-list [
        append gui-layout compose/deep [
        box (choice-name) [print [(emp-id) (choice-id)]]
        ]
    ]

    view layout gui-layout
]

screen1
```

Now, if you click someone then click 'back', the menu grows.  (And if you click someone else, the second menu has grown too.)  One workaround(?) I've found is to put `clear emp-list` before `view layout gui-layout` to fix the first screen from doing this.  Yet, if I `print emp-list` in there I can see that it's not `emp-list` that is growing.  How can this be?

Comment: I've also tried `clear gui-layout` and making the list and the layout local using `has` (or `function` for `screen2`), but neither of these achieve the result of just drawing a new list each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a persistence feature of functions.

See

```
persist: has [ a ] [ a: [] append a random 100 print a ]


no-persist: has [ a ] [ a: copy [] append a random 100 print a ]
```

To do what you want, put a 'copy before each series you're appending to

```
gui-layout: copy [ text "click your name" ]
```

and

```
gui-layout: copy/deep [
        box "<-- back to names" [screen1]
        text reform ["clicked id " emp-id ", now choose below"]
    ]
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I was unaware of that feature, obviously.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a VID question at all...hmm, I should have read it more closely.  :-P